# Proof verification: Construction of $\{x_n\}_n \subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $\{y_n\}_n \subset \mathbb{Q^c} $ that both converge to a real number $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can anyone check my proof. Im new to writing proof and i'm not really confident about it. Any feedback is appreciated thank you.

> Show that there exists two sequence strictly increasing such that $\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers and $\{y_n\}_n$ is a sequence of irrational numbers that both converge to a real number $x$.

---

In the statement, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x_n\}_n=x$ so it must be bounded by $x$.Let's first construct the sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ of rational numbers in the invervall $(x-1,x)$.

For $n=1$ , by the density of  $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists a rational number $r_1$ s.t: $$x-1<r_1<x.$$

For $n=2$, again by the density of  $\mathbb{Q}$ we will have a rational number $r_2$ st: $$r_1<r_2<x.$$

...

For $n=N$ we will have: $$r_{N-1}<r_N<x.$$

We have shown that we can created a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ of rational number that is strictly increasing and bounded by $x$.

Without loss of generality, we can created a sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ of irrational number that converge to $x$ knowing that $\mathbb{Q^c}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Is my proof correct ? Any feedback is appreciated thank you.

Comment: That's not enough. The sequence $1 - 1/n$ is bounded from above by $2$ but does not converge to it.

Comment: So, what is your question???

Comment: proof verification

Comment: @santiago, but the limit converge to 1

Comment: ok i get it now my proof does not show that it converge. So i guess the best way is to proof by exemple,

Comment: The statement of the problem has problems. You need to start with x, not have it floating around at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Take the sequence $x_i=x- \frac{1}{i}$ for all $i$. Then $\left\{ x_i \right\}_i \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and this sequence clearly converges to $x$. For the other sequence, let $\left\{y_i \right\}_i \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^c$, $y_i= x- \frac{1}{\sqrt{i^2+1}}$. For $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $y_i \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and clearly $\lim y_i= x$. Both of these are strictly increasing.

Similar sequences can be constructed for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: thx, can you give any feedback on my proof please? thx you.

Comment: In your proof, you have not guaranteed convergence to $x$. If you can show, for instance, $\sup(x_n)=x$, then your proof is sufficient. This will be difficult with a sequence that is not explicitly constructed, like yours.

Comment: Ok thank you, all the anwser here peoples have shown a proof by exemple that is why.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by example: $$x_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ $$y_n=e-\frac{1}{n}$$ where both sequences are strictly increasing and converge to the irrational number $e$.

Comment: yeah your sequences does work . thank you. Please I would like some feedback about my proof, I'm not very confident about proof writing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n = -1/n, y_n = -\sqrt 2/n.$

Comment: thx very much , also i would like to know if my proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof as it stands is not complete as pointed out in the comments. You have simply created a sequence of rationals that are bounded above by x. That doesn't imply it converges to x.